# Splunk: How to use multiple regular expressions in one query?

Tags: regex, splunk, splunk-query

I have four regular expressions which I would like to use for one query. All the regular expressions are okay for itselves but I did not find out how to use them in pne query together:

These are the regular expressions:

Expression 1:

```
(?<time>\d{4}.\d{2}.\d{2}\s\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{3})
```

Expression 2:

```
deviceId...(?<deviceId>\d+)
```

Expression 3:

```
error....code...(?<errorCode>\w+)
```

Expression 4:

```
"\"message...(?<errorMessage>.*?)\"
```

And I tried this among some other things in Splunk:

```
 source="xyz.log" |rex field=_raw  "(?<time>\d{4}.\d{2}.\d{2}\s\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{3}) deviceId...(?<deviceId>\d+) error....code...(?<errorCode>\w+) "\"message...(?<errorMessage>.*?)\"" |table time deviceId errorCode errorMessage
```

But I got an error.

Comment: Have you tried just or-ing the expresions? e.g. (expression1|expression2|expression3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to combine the regexes using the OR `|` operator, but it's far easier to use multiple `rex` commands.  Using multiple commands has the advantage of allowing the keywords to be order-independent.

```
source="xyz.log" 
|rex field=_raw  "(?<time>\d{4}.\d{2}.\d{2}\s\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{3})" 
|rex "deviceId...(?<deviceId>\d+)"
|rex "error....code...(?<errorCode>\w+)"
|rex "\\\"message...(?<errorMessage>.*?)\\\"" 
|table time deviceId errorCode errorMessage
```

Answer (score 3):

I generally try to avoid putting multiple field extracts in a single [`rex`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/rex)

Instead, I go for sequential ones like this:

```
<search>
| rex field=_raw "(?<ip>\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+):"
| rex field=_raw "\d+:(?<port>\d+)"
| rex field=_raw "\d+:\d+\s+(?<msg>.+)"
<more stuff here>
```

In this example, I'm pulling an IP, port, and some message afterwards into three new fields: `ip`, `port`, `msg`

Of course, if you *can* this should be done in [`props.conf`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/Admin/Propsconf) ...but that's not always possible